# Difference by Group using dplyr and data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I want to calculate difference by groups. Although I referred [R: Function “diff” over various groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569177/r-function-diff-over-various-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread on SO, for unknown reason, I am unable to find the difference. I have tried three methods : a) `spread` b) `dplyr::mutate` with `base::diff()` c) `data.table` with `base::diff()`. While a) works, I am unsure how I can solve this problem using b) and c).

**Description about the data:**
I have revenue data for the product by year. I have categorized years >= 2013 as Period 2 (called `P2`), and years < 2013 as Period 1 (called `P1`).

**Sample data:**

```
dput(Test_File)
structure(list(Ship_Date = c(2010, 2010, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2011, 2017), Name = c("Apple", 
"Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", 
"Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Mango", "Pineapple"), 
    Revenue = c(5, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 25, 25, 25, 1, 2, 4, 5, 
    7)), .Names = c("Ship_Date", "Name", "Revenue"), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Expected Output**

```
dput(Diff_Table)
structure(list(Name = c("Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Pineapple"
), P1 = c(15, 58, 5, NA), P2 = c(75, 7, NA, 7), Diff = c(60, 
-51, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Name", "P1", "P2", "Diff"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

**Here's my code:**

**Method 1: Using `spread` [Works]**

```
data.table::setDT(Test_File)
cutoff<-2013
Test_File[Test_File$Ship_Date>=cutoff,"Ship_Period"]<-"P2"
Test_File[Test_File$Ship_Date<cutoff,"Ship_Period"]<-"P1"

Diff_Table<- Test_File %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Ship_Period,Name) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Ship_Period, Name,Revenue) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::distinct() %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = Ship_Period,value = Revenue) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Diff = `P2` - `P1`)
```

**Method 2: Using `dplyr` [Doesn't work: NAs are generated in `Diff` column.]**

```
Diff_Table<- Test_File %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Ship_Period,Name) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Ship_Period, Name,Revenue) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::distinct() %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Name,Ship_Period, Revenue) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Ship_Period,Name) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Diff = diff(Revenue))
```

**Method 3: Using `data.table` [Doesn't work: It generates all zeros in `Diff` column.]**

```
Test_File[,Revenue1 := sum(Revenue),by=c("Ship_Period","Name")]
Diff_Table<-Test_File[,.(Diff = diff(Revenue1)),by=c("Ship_Period","Name")]
```

**Question:** Can someone please help me with method 2 and method 3 above? I am fairly new to R so I apologize if my work sounds too basic. I am still learning this language.

Comment: Should the value of `P1` for `Pineapple` be `NA` ?

Comment: Yes, if doesn't exist.

Comment: Does that mean that the accepted answer gives a wrong result?

Comment: @Jogo - Good observation! I wouldn't consider akrun's answer as wrong because `NA`-`number` = `NA` and `number` - `NA` = `NA`. So, I would believe that it doesn't matter much. I created those entries to ensure that the code doesn't blow up when one of `P1` or `P2` are missing. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Test_File)`), grouped by the run-length-id of 'Name' and 'Name', get the `sum` of 'Revenue', reshape it to 'wide' format with `dcast`, get the difference between 'P2' and 'P1' and assign (`:=`) it to 'Diff'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Test_File)[, .(Revenue = sum(Revenue)),
   .(grp=rleid(Name), Name)], Name~ paste0("P", rowid(Name)), 
        value.var = "Revenue")[, Diff := P2 - P1][]
#        Name P1 P2 Diff
#1:     Apple 15 75   60
#2:    Banana 58  7  -51
#3:     Mango  5 NA   NA
#4: Pineapple  7 NA   NA
```

---

Or for third case, i.e. `base R`, we create a grouping column based on whether the adjacent elements in 'Name' are the same or not ('grp'), then `aggregate` the 'Revenue' by 'Name' and 'grp' to find the `sum`, create a sequence column, `reshape` it to 'wide' and `transform` the dataset to create the 'Diff' column

```
Test_File$grp <- with(Test_File, cumsum(c(TRUE, Name[-1]!=Name[-length(Name)])))
d1 <- aggregate(Revenue~Name +grp, Test_File, sum)
d1$Seq <- with(d1, ave(seq_along(Name), Name, FUN = seq_along))
transform(reshape(d1[-2], idvar = "Name", timevar = "Seq", 
            direction = "wide"), Diff = Revenue.2- Revenue.1)
```

---

The `tidyverse` method can also be done using

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Test_File %>% 
       group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, Name[-1]!=Name[-length(Name)])), Name)  %>%
       summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
       group_by(Name) %>% 
       mutate(Seq = paste0("P", row_number()))  %>% 
       select(-grp) %>% 
       spread(Seq, Revenue) %>% 
       mutate(Diff = P2-P1)
 #Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
 #Groups: Name [4]

#      Name    P1    P2  Diff
#      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     Apple    15    75    60
#2    Banana    58     7   -51
#3     Mango     5    NA    NA
#4 Pineapple     7    NA    NA
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments to use only `diff` function

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Test_File)[, .(Revenue = sum(Revenue)), .(Name, grp = rleid(Name))
  ][, .(P1 = Revenue[1L], P2 = Revenue[2L], Diff = diff(Revenue)) , Name]
#        Name P1 P2 Diff
#1:     Apple 15 75   60
#2:    Banana 58  7  -51
#3:     Mango  5 NA   NA
#4: Pineapple  7 NA   NA
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
Test_File %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, Name[-1]!=Name[-length(Name)])), Name)  %>%
   summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   summarise(P1 = first(Revenue), P2 = last(Revenue)) %>%
   mutate(Diff = P2-P1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, akrun. You are awesome. I have two questions: a) It seems that you are relying on wide format for calculating the difference. I apologize but I was looking for a solution without using wide format. For instance, by using `diff`. Now, the bigger question is whether this is even possible without going to wide format. I would appreciate your thoughts. b) can you please explain `.(grp=rleid(Name), Name)], Name~ paste0("P", rowid(Name))` in your code? Sorry if this is too basic question.

Comment: @watchtower Are you looking for a solution using only `diff` ?

Comment: @akrun...if it's possible to use `diff` and arrive at the same result, it would expand my understanding. I initially thought of solving this using wide format, but I was distracted by the SO thread I found. Thanks again for all your help. I always learn a lot from your posts.

Comment: Quick q: in your `diff` solution, can you please explain what `.(Name, grp = rleid(Name)` does? I understood the purpose of `rleid` but I am unsure whether new column will be created or you are specifying groupings. I believe groupings are specified using `by`. Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: @watchtower It is a summarising step and the grouping column is not added into the original data.  You can specify the `by`, but the general format is `data.table[i, j, by]`

Comment: Many thanks. I am slowly able to understand your excellent post. One last q if you don't mind: could you please point out flaws in my Method 2? I am still trying to wrap my head around this. Again, my apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: @watchtower  You dont need to apologize.  We all started from 0.  Regarding your code, I would use `summarise` instead of `mutate(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%` which also will have the big dataset to process for the next step and makes it slower.  Rule of thumb is that if you are doing any filtering etc, then do it as first step and then do the group by and other process (but it depends on what kind of output you want)

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(Test_File)
T <- Test_File[, .(P=sum(Revenue)),by=.(Ship_Date, Name)]
T[Ship_Date>=2013][T[Ship_Date<2013][CJ(Name=T$Name, unique=TRUE), on="Name"], on="Name"][,`:=`(P1=i.P, P2=P, Diff=P-i.P)][] 
#    Ship_Date      Name  P i.Ship_Date i.P P1 P2 Diff
# 1:      2017     Apple 75        2010  15 15 75   60
# 2:      2016    Banana  7        2012  58 58  7  -51
# 3:        NA     Mango NA        2011   5  5 NA   NA
# 4:      2017 Pineapple  7          NA  NA NA  7   NA
```

Or with only the wanted columns:

```
T[Ship_Date>=2013][T[Ship_Date<2013][CJ(Name=T$Name, unique=TRUE), on="Name"], on="Name"][,`:=`(P1=i.P, P2=P, Diff=P-i.P)][,.(Name, P1, P2, Diff)]
#         Name P1 P2 Diff
# 1:     Apple 15 75   60
# 2:    Banana 58  7  -51
# 3:     Mango  5 NA   NA
# 4: Pineapple NA  7   NA
```

Here is a variant using `setnames()`:

```
setnames(T[Ship_Date>=2013][T[Ship_Date<2013][CJ(Name=T$Name, unique=TRUE), on="Name"], on="Name"], 
         c("P", "i.P"), c("P2", "P1"))[, Diff:=P2-P1][]
```